# How to print null without quotes when using String.format

Tags: java, string

I am working on one program in Java that is using String.format() to print a string. Below scenario is:

***StringJava.class***

```
public static String myString = "This is my name : "\%s\""
```

Suppose in my main class I am using String.format() in such a way that if we pass some value it will return the respective string. For example:

```
System.out.println(String.format(StringJava.myString, some_value))
```

It will give me the expected result that is : This is my name "some_value"

But if i try to pass null values like this:

```
System.out.println(String.format(StringJava.myString, null))
```

It will give me the result that is: `This is my name "null"`

But I want my result as: `This is my name null`

How can I fix this "null" issue?

Comment: If you want quotes around some things but not around others, you either need to explicit quotes around things, or have separate format strings for the null and non-null cases.

Comment: Have you tried to concatenate the \"%s"\ ? Also, in you code it's written "\%s"\ instead of \"%s"\

Comment: Yeah i got it but suppose there are more than one attributes that we need to specify in format, then do we need to create more strings for each values?

Comment: @JeroSquartini yeah i just updated my code. Typo error while writing question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of specifying the quotes in the `myString` itself, write a small utility method to process the value before feeding it to the `String.format()` method. Within this utility method, you can check for null and treat differently.

```
public static String myString = "This is my name : %s"

System.out.println(String.format(StringJava.myString, wrapWithQuotes("some_value")));
System.out.println(String.format(StringJava.myString, wrapWithQuotes(null)));

private String wrapWithQuotes(String input) {
    return (input != null) ? '"' + input + '"' : null;
}
```

Comment: `String.format("\"%s\"", input)` is a bit overkill when it could aswell be `'"' + input + '"'`

Answer (score 1):

You should change the constant `myString` to a method.

```
public static String myString(String name) {
    return String.format("This is my name : %s", name == null ? null : "\"" + name + "\"");
}
```

and

```
 System.out.println(StringJava.myString("Jhon"));
 System.out.println(StringJava.myString(null));
```

output

```
This is my name : "Jhon"
This is my name : null
```